# Polynomials - getting wrong answer using Euclidean algorithm

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

I am finding the GCD of $a = x^3 + 11/3x^2 + 17/4x + 3/2$ and $b = 3x^2 + 22/3x + 17/4$ using the Euclidean algorithm. So I divide $a/b$ and get $q$ and $r$ such that $a = qb + r$. Then, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_algorithm), I set the new $a = b$, $b = r$, and repeat until $b = 0$, at which point the GCD of the original $a$ and $b$ will be the current $a$ value.

Iteration 1:
$$a = x^3 + \dfrac{11}{3}x^2 + \dfrac{17}{4}x + \dfrac{3}{2}$$
$$b = 3x^2 + \dfrac{22}{3}x + \dfrac{17}{4}$$
$$x^3 + \dfrac{11}{3}x^2 + \dfrac{17}{4}x + \dfrac{3}{2} = \left(\dfrac{1}{3}x + \dfrac{11}{27}\right) \times \left(3x^2 + \dfrac{22}{3}x + \dfrac{17}{4}\right) - \dfrac{25}{162}x - \dfrac{25}{108}$$
Iteration 2:
$$a = 3x^2 + \dfrac{22}{3}x + \dfrac{17}{4}$$
$$b = -\dfrac{25}{162}x - \dfrac{25}{108}$$
$$3x^2 + \dfrac{22}{3}x + \dfrac{17}{4} = \left(-\dfrac{486}{25}x - \dfrac{459}{25}\right) \times \left(-\dfrac{25}{162}x - \dfrac{25}{108}\right) + 0$$

Then I set $a = b = -\dfrac{25}{162}x - \dfrac{25}{108}$ and $b = r = 0$. Since $b$ is zero, the GCD is $a$.

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd%28x3%2B11%2F3x2%2B17%2F4x%2B3%2F2%2C+3x2%2B22%2F3x%2B17%2F4%29) gives the GCD as $1/6x + 1/4$. So what did I do wrong? (I'm sure it's simple, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...)

Comment: Don't forget that the GCD is only defined up to a constant factor.  This doesn't completely explain your discrepancy though (459 has a factor of 17 which is nowhere to be found in $1/6 x + 1/4$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:
$$-\frac{25}{162}x - \frac{25}{108} = -\frac{25}{27}\left(\frac 1 6 x + \frac 1 4\right)$$

The GCD of 2 polynomials is determined up to a constant (aka a *unit*).

Comment: Is there any particular rule as to which constant should be used? Wolfram|Alpha certainly seems to be using some sort of rule... I have heard that you should take the monic version, or that you should take the primitive parts, but neither of these yield the 1/6 and 1/4 coefficients. Or should any scaling of the polynomial work for squarefree, distinct degree, equal degree, etc. factorization (which is what I need this for)?

Comment: Monic is nice. Or else a version with integer coefficients ($2x+3$). I'm surprised as well that W|M didn't do that. I do not believe there is any particular rule though.